# How do I prevent auto-completion in Terminal from escaping the $ sign

Tags: 12.04, command-line

In 10.04 Terminal I can enter the command:
  cat $MYDIR/a
then hit tab and auto-completion expands it to:
  cat /home/me/abc.txt

(I have defined MYDIR in my .bashrc)

In 12.04 it auto completes to:
  cat \$MYDIR/abc.txt
and gives a no such file error

How can I get the 10.04 behaviour in this respect?

Answer (score 1):

This one is complex. It is not really a bug, but an unintended consequence of a feature: [see this discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00296.html).

But yes, that is the behavior of bash 4.2, and many people have complained that it is a bug. The solution is to either downgrade the bash to the 4.1 version, or upgrade it to 4.2.29, where this bug has been ironed out.

A temporary solution is described [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-auto-complete-of-environment-variables-613203/#post3055141)

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
complete -v -F _cd $nospace $filenames cd
```